# Google Drive Sdk sharing permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a question about google drive sdk php

Can google drvie sdk change sharing permissions of many files with php?

I have read the document, but just find the way changing sharing permissions of one file with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes PHP samples for all methods, including those for managing sharing, e.g. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

Comment: thanks you for your help. But how can i change files permission to "anyone with link" with php sdk ?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing to learn everything about sharing